# `TransientPropertyValueException` when updating Spring Boot from 2.6.7 to 2.7.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following code in a Spring boot integration test class:

```java
@Autowired
private AddressRepository addressRepository;
// other Repositories that all extend CrudRepository 

@BeforeEach
void init(){
  Address address = new Address();
  // Set up address
  address = addressRepository.save(address); //<-- address properly persisted?

  Building building = new Building();
  building.setAddress(address); 
  buildingRepository.save(building); //<-- throws error
}
```

where

```java
@Entity
class Building {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  Address address;
  //...
}
```

and the pom.xml:

```xml
//...
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>//<-- upping the version breaks things
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
//...
```

which runs smooth on Spring Boot 2.6.7. After upgrading to 2.7.2 however, saving the `building` now throws a `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation`. If I understood correctly, Spring thinks that `address` is not yet persisted and thus cannot store its reference in the `building`. But it is already persisted in line two of `init`?

What am I missing?

Comment: You have no transaction in BeforeEach that's why it fails. But I cannot tell you why it worked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: @Transactional in tests should not be done, except you know what you are doing, H2 is weird.

#### Why is `@Transactional` not a good idea?

Every test is already wrapped in its own transaction by default ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/testing.html#testing-introduction)). That's why it worked beforehand. Nesting another `Transaction` seems to actually confuse Spring as it does not seem to autocommit on every operation anymore as it is supposed to do.

#### H2 is weird

The problem was that `Address` (please note that `Address` is not my real code but an example of a simalar relation of objects) used an `UUID` as its `id`.

We use H2 as a DB for testing which did not create a proper table for `Address` but messed up the id column with a wrong data type with the new update. Thus, it could not find any `Address` by `id`. That's why the JPAContext errored saying that the address was not existent.

Adding

```
  //...
  @Entity
  public class Address{
  @Column(columnDefinition = 'uuid') <-- add this line
  @Id
  UUID addrId;
  //...
}
```

helps M2 to determine the correct column type and solves the problem.